# Vue - how to use @ in background-image url

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

In `<style>` part, I want to use @ for the path for `background-image` like below:

`background-image: url("@/assets/images/banner.png");`

However, error occurs:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./@/assets/images/banner.png in ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/pages/home/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=5b685826&scoped=true&lang=scss&
```

How can I resolve it? I use `vue-cli` to generate the application.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir : 'public',
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  pluginOptions: {
    webpack: {
      dir: [
        './webpack'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the [vue-loader docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules), what you've got should be fine provided your image actually exists at `src/assets/images/banner.png`. Is that the case?

Comment: i would presume that inside a component, any local `<style>` declarations will be scoped (maybe even in the builder module resolution phase), so the issue may be that in such cases, the webpack alilas resolution will assume a relative path. did you try using an explicit relative path? also, did you try prepending `@` with a `/`?

Comment: I tried `background-image: url("../../assets/images/banner.png");` which works

Answer (score 1):

add'~'before '@' , like blow

```
background-image: url("~@/assets/images/banner.png")
```

Comment: not working `This dependency was not found`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a vue + webpack setup.
Finally, I ended up using the resolve-url-loader for webpack which is great (see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader)

```
npm install resolve-url-loader --save-dev
```

To correctly use it, it must be loaded between sass-loader and css-loader! Also, source-maps are required for loaders preceding resolve-url-loader.

To achieve that, my vue.config.js looks like:

```js
....

module.exports = {
    ....

    chainWebpack: config => {

        ....

        config.module
            .rule('scss')
            .oneOf('vue')
            .use('resolve-url-loader')
            .loader('resolve-url-loader').options({
                keepQuery: true
            })
            .before('sass-loader');

    },

    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                sourceMap: true,
                }
                
            }       
        }
    }

};
```